# Is there a way to mock an artisan command and assert if it ran in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, testing, mocking, laravel-artisan

I have a piece of code that executes an artisan command. I want to write a test to assert if it ran with the right options.

So, essentially I'm looking for some magic like:

`Queue::fake();` and `Queue::assertPushed()` but for artisan commands.

Comment: Does [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/console-tests) help you ?

Comment: Did my suggestion help you or are you still stuck?

Answer (score 3):

I believe your best approach is to use facade [mocks](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#mocking-facades). This has a little less features than a faked class in `Laravel`, but in my simply case, it works great for artisan commands.

Controller code should use the facade.

```
public function yourRoute()
{
    Artisan::call('my:cmd');
}
```

Now you can utilize the facade mock, my simply example i wrote and tested it working.

```
public function testArtisanMock()
{
    Artisan::shouldReceive('call')
        ->once()
        ->with('my:cmd');

    $response = $this->get('/artisan');
    $response->assertOk();
}
```